# What are the invariant factors of $(\mathbb{Z}/(1000))^\times$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

I'm curious about the invariant factors of $(\mathbb{Z}/(1000))^\times$. I put down
$$
(\mathbb{Z}/(1000))^\times\cong(\mathbb{Z}/(8))^\times\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/(125))^\times
$$

It's easy to compute by hand that $(\mathbb{Z}/(8))^\times\cong\mathbb{Z}/(2)\oplus\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ and by a theorem of Gauss, $\mathbb{Z}/(125))^\times\cong\mathbb{Z}/(100)$ as it is cyclic.

Does this mean the list of invariant factors is just $(2,2,100)$?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if the invariant factors of Z/2 x Z/2 x Z/100 are (2,2,100)?  I think that is the definition of invariant factors, isn't it?